# Get videos with Sony SDK (RX100 V)

Tags: sony

I found on the API reference that I can get Images from the camera but can I get also videos? I did not found anything about that..

I wanted to develop a program that triggers the camera to start a slow motion video and retrive it after, is that possible?

Best regards!
Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call the "startMovieRec" function to start recording. You can then call the "stopMovieRec" function to stop recording. After this you can call the "getContentList" function to get a list of the images, videos, etc.. that are on the camera. You can download the video through the url. Please let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: m5 have bad firmware. Don't have stopMovieRec
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260741/sony-camera-dsc-rx100m5-remote-api

Answer (score 0):

I think is not posible.
My Sony RX100 V have only this options:

```
"getVersions"
"getMethodTypes"
"getApplicationInfo"
"getAvailableApiList"
"getEvent"
"stopRecMode"
"startMovieRec"
"startLiveview"
"stopLiveview"
"actZoom"
"setShootMode"
"getShootMode"
"getAvailableShootMode"
"getSupportedShootMode"
"getExposureCompensation"
"getAvailableExposureCompensation"
"getSupportedExposureCompensation"
```

All other versions 2,3,4,6,7,8... have a good firmware. Not 5 version